# Pose planning for reflective surfaces. Difficult mathematical / geometrical problem . Possible with blender?

Tags: optimization, rendering

first of all this is not a blender - specific question, but i would like to realize it if it is possible with blender since it is open source and can be combined with python programming.

I am working on a project for deflectometry. The problem with deflectometry is that the reflections for specular surfaces are defined the the surface normal of the object. 
If you have highly curved objects, you need to move the sensor around in order to get measurement data for the complete object.

More precisely:

I want to get all the positions necessary to measure the whole object with some kind of an optimization algorithm.

The input of this algorithm would be an arbitrary CAD model, the focal length of the desired lenses, the working distance between object and sensor, the size of the projecting screen and the distance between camera and screen.
The output would be the number of sensor-positions needed, as well as the positions (x,y,z,euler angles).

I know this is a difficult mathematical problem. The first idea is that each surface point gets an additional attribute called "seen", which means that the reflection of the screen at this point gets seen by a camera. If the attribute "seen" is true for each points, then the algorithm ends and the positions get returned.

Is this problem possible to realize with blender + python ? Would be happy to get some ideas, or maybe some libraries for a similar problem.